# Excel VBA: How to trigger an Event from code?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick event that opens a listbox in the target cell. I was asked to provide the same functionality via a button instead of (or in addition to) the double-click.

In the button's Click event I entered:

```
Call Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(Selection,true)
```

...so the button simply "doubleclicks" the cell. It seems to work well, but before I start using this technique throughout my project, I'd like to know if there are pitfalls I should be aware of.

What are the best practices when calling an event, either from another event or from a standard code module?

Comment: Why don't you just define a public sub or function that does your actions, then you can call it whenever you want, (including from inside your BeforeDoubleClickEvent).

Comment: Yes there is a major pitfall. Let me post an answer...

Comment: Thanks to you both. Sam, I'm trying your suggestion, but moving all the code from the Event module to a standard module seems complicated. I have a lot of controls to refer to, and I can't just say "Me.CancelButton" anymore. Do you know where I can read about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'd like to know if there are pitfalls I should be aware of.

Yes there is one major pitfall. The `Selection` necessarily might not be a range. See this example

1. Insert a button
2. Insert a blank chart
3. Insert an image in the chart. Let the image be highlighted

[image]

Let's say we have this code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(Selection, True)
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox Target.Address
End Sub
```

Now press the button and you will get an error.

[image]

The worksheet events **WILL** fire when they **NEED** too... They won't when the selection is not appropriate.

Having said that you **CAN** make your command button code work like this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '~~> Check if what the user selected is a valid range
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        Call Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(Selection, True)
    Else
        MsgBox "Not a Valid Range"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox Target.Address
End Sub
```

But then where all and what all **CHECKS** will you place :) The best way is to place it in a Sub as @Sam suggested and then call it either from `Button/Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick`.

If you still want to call it from a button then ensure that all relevant checks are in place including a proper error handler.

Comment: great analysis and explanation